# Input type number does not accept decimal in iOS

Tags: ios, html, input

I am working on an web /hybrid mobile application using Meteor + React. I have multiple input fields with type `number`. Everything works fine for Android and Web but not for iOS.

I have this sample code (React Component)

```
<InputBox containerClassName="input-field gray-border center"
          autoComplete="off" 
          className="validate center-align"
          type="number" name="currentWeight" unit="kgs"
          value=""/>
```

What may be causing this one, and how can I fix this one? I've been scratching my head through this for some hours, considering I also have searched for other solutions to no avail. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give **step="0.01"** to support 2 decimal number

```
<InputBox containerClassName="input-field gray-border center"
              autoComplete="off" 
              className="validate center-align"
              type="number" step="0.01" name="currentWeight" unit="kgs"
              value=""/>
```